# Android KitKat Bluetooth connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-4.4-kitkat

Am i the only one having problems connecting to the bluetooth with startBluetoothSco?  This works fine in all versions of Android except 4.4.2 (kitkat).  Any suggestions?  And yes, I have verified that I am connected to Bluetooth before I call this.  Did something changed in 4.4.2?

Here is my code:

```
am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

Following your suggestion i did the following, but this is driving me nuts!  What am I doing wrong. I have the listener in my MainActivity as follows...

```
private final BluetoothHandler.Listener mBluetoothListener = new BluetoothHandler.Listener() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionComplete() {
        final BluetoothHandler bluetoothHandler = mBluetoothHandler;

        if (bluetoothHandler != null) {
            am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
        }
    }

};
```

Then in my OnCreate I initialize the BluetoothHandler

```
if(mBluetoothHandler == null){
        mBluetoothHandler = new BluetoothHandler(5000, mBluetoothListener);
    } else {
        mBluetoothHandler.stopSco();
        mBluetoothHandler.stop();
        mBluetoothHandler = null;
    }

if (!mBluetoothHandler.isAudioConnected()) {
                mBluetoothHandler.start(mContext);
            }
```

The problem I'm having is that the listener doesn't detect when a BT device connects or even says that one is connected.  Any suggestions?  I appreciate your help...

Comment: What versions of Android does not have this issue? Only 4.4.2 introduced that behavior?

Comment: All versions from ICS up work fine until I get to KitKat.

Answer (score 1):

The functionality of `startBluetoothSco()` changed between API 17 and API 18. In API 17, this function initiates a virtual call via SCO. In API 18, the function opens a raw SCO link. Some Bluetooth units will only respond to a virtual call.

Unfortunately it doesn't seem that Google have given us an option of choosing whether to open a virtual call or raw link so if you require a virtual call, you will need to ensure your app is built with API 17.

From the Android Developer reference:

> "NOTE: up to and including API version JELLY_BEAN_MR1, this method
>   initiates a virtual voice call to the bluetooth headset. After API
>   version JELLY_BEAN_MR2 only a raw SCO audio connection is
>   established."

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#startBluetoothSco()

Comment: Thanks!  I still don't understand why my phone can launch Google Now through Bluetooth properly but in my app when I use startBluetoothSco() nothing happens with either API 17 or 18.  I know my app works because it works on all other phones other than my HTC m8.  Any insight into this?

Answer (score 0):

Which device do you use? I know that there is sometimes a Bluetooth problem with nexus devices (nexus 5 with kit at also) as described here:

http://www.androidpolice.com/2013/12/28/bug-watch-many-nexus-devices-still-suffer-from-assorted-bluetooth-issues/

Comment: I am using a galaxy s3

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with an app I was developming. Upong updating my phone to KitKat, the SCO connection to my car stopped working.
I finally come up with a solultion using a somehow private api in the bluetooth headset profile, while keeping my code compatible with API 19.

Fist I'm checking if current version is API 17, in that case, I use the standard startBluetoothSco from AudioManager, if not the case, I get the current BluetoothHeadset profile and use the following method to create the virtual call sco link (I can't take credit for this, I found it in the Google TalkBack application):

```
class BluetoothHeadsetCompatWrapper {
    private static final Class<?> CLASS_BluetoothHeadset = BluetoothHeadset.class;
    private static final Method METHOD_startScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall = CompatUtils.getMethod(
            CLASS_BluetoothHeadset, "startScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall", BluetoothDevice.class);
    private static final Method METHOD_stopScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall = CompatUtils.getMethod(
            CLASS_BluetoothHeadset, "stopScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall", BluetoothDevice.class);

    private final BluetoothHeadset mHeadset;

    public BluetoothHeadsetCompatWrapper(BluetoothHeadset headset) {
        mHeadset = headset;
    }

    public boolean startScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall(BluetoothDevice device) {
        return (Boolean) CompatUtils.invoke(mHeadset, false, METHOD_startScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall,
                device);
    }

    public boolean stopScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall(BluetoothDevice device) {
        return (Boolean) CompatUtils.invoke(mHeadset, false, METHOD_stopScoUsingVirtualVoiceCall,
                device);
    }
}
```

I found this solution when I was looking into the BluetoothHeadset code and found out the method actually exists, but it's hidden to the compiler https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothHeadset.java

I know my anwser may be late, but I posted anyway to help others.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I'm a bit confused as to how to use this though.  I'm learning Java as I go.  I have looked at the example project you gave and I am not getting my listener to detect the bluetooth connection.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Pretty simple actually, just follow the sample from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#Profiles

Comment: Please see the edited code above in the main question.  Thanks @user1886080

Comment: I figured it out! My fault, I forgot to change my build target from 17 to the latest. Spent 2 days on this! Thanks, it works great!

Comment: @user1886080 your solution works however I notice that on the first connect to Bluetooth sco there is a long delay.  If the app is already open and connect to Bluetooth again it's immediate.  Any solution for the first connect?